# How to calculate 8-hours work day and Finish Date for Excel Project Plan Tracker

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, project-management, gantt

I have this example created in Microsoft Project, but I want to make the same using Microsoft Excel.
Need help in calculation of hours and calculating next date based on **8-hours day**.

Like, if you see in "Sub-Series 1" Task 1 to Task 4 especially Task 3 of Sub-Series 1.
The duration for Task 3 is 4hrs and the 'Finish Date' changes to next day date, as it sums up with the hours for previous tasks (Task 1 & Task 2) as well, as the sum is >8 so the 'Finish Date' changes to next date.

Please help in figuring out the Formulae to achieve duration in *'days'* and '*Finish Date'* for 'Sub-Series' & for 'Series 1'.

*Manual Inputs*: Duration and Start date for 'Tasks' of each 'Sub-Series'

*Formulae required for:* 'Finish date' and sum of 'Duration' into days

Thanks in advance and best regards,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to achieve the desired outputs by the help of 3 helper columns. if anyone have better solution please do share it. Thanks!

F5 cell is manual input for Start date.

H5 contains `=IF(J5=0,F5+J5,IF(AND(J5=1,K5=0),(F5+J5)-1,IF(AND($J5<>$J4,K5>0),WORKDAY($F5,($J5-$J4)),IF(AND($J5=$J4,K5>0),$F5,IF(AND($J6<>$J5,K5>0),(F5+J5)-1,$F5)))))`

G5 contains `=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(H5)={1,7}),WORKDAY(H5,1),IF(J5=0,F5+J5,IF(AND(J5=1,K5=0),(F5+J5)-1,IF(AND($J5<>$J4,K5>0),WORKDAY($F5,($J5-$J4)),IF(AND($J5=$J4,K5>0),$F5,IF(AND($J6<>$J5,K5>0),(F5+J5)-1,$F5))))))`

F6 contains `=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(H5)={1,7}),WORKDAY(H5,1),IF(AND($I6<>$I5,$K5=0),$H5+1,$H5))`

I6 contains running SUM `=SUM(I5,E6)` and Cell J5 `=QUOTIENT(I5,8)`  and Cell K5 `=MOD(I5,8)`

Thanks everyone! & @PeterH

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel has built in templates for many types of file.

And even template gantt charts.

Go to file -> and search for a gantt chart.

[image]

Comment: in all of the examples there, the duration of tasks is not in hours... and i need 8-hours day !!! Thank you

Comment: I get what you mean now, for you duration, you could have something like a look up table, so 15 mins = 00:15, and 1 day = 24:00 and then you can just add this to the start time, for this you would need fixed points for the available duration in the look up table, like every multiple of 15 mins would be fine im guessing